# split paragraph into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I had code like below

```
return fetch(URI + 'api/brewing/1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

          var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(responseJson["data"][0]["steps"]);
          var stringData = JSON.stringify(parsedResponse);
          })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
```

And get data like below

**After soaking your filter in a warm water bath for at least five minutes, drop it into the bottom of your siphons top component, or hopper, and hook to the bottom of the hoppers glass tubing.,Fill your siphon bottom component.,Insert the hopper, filter and all.**

I want to split the paragraph after **dot** and **comma** delimiter into an array so I can loop all the data. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your existing code so we can help you fix it.  This isn't a code request service so you need to show us what you've already tried.

Comment: `str.split(/[.,]+/)`

Comment: `String.split()` ? For the record, this is a very basic method you learn in every tutorial.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @Archer I've edit it

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions below?  One of them does exactly what you've asked for.

Comment: Ty in advanced @Archer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to split the string by *dot* followed by *comma*:

```js
var s = 'After soaking your filter in a warm water bath for at least five minutes, drop it into the bottom of your siphons top component, or hopper, and hook to the bottom of the hoppers glass tubing.,Fill your siphon bottom component.,Insert the hopper, filter and all.'
s = s.split('.,');
console.log(s);
```

**OR:** Using RegEx

```js
var s = 'After soaking your filter in a warm water bath for at least five minutes, drop it into the bottom of your siphons top component, or hopper, and hook to the bottom of the hoppers glass tubing.,Fill your siphon bottom component.,Insert the hopper, filter and all.'
s = s.split(/(?:\.\,)/g);
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

try `str.split(/[,.]+/);` to split the paragraph after dot and comma delimiter into an array

```js
let str ="After soaking your filter., in a warm water bath for at least five minutes, drop it into the bottom of your siphons top component, or hopper,. and hook to the bottom of the hoppers glass tubing.,Fill your siphon bottom component.,Insert the hopper, filter and all.";

let splittedArray = str.split(".,");

console.log(splittedArray);
```

Comment: @Archer sorry, now I got Questions. I have updated my answer. Thanks